# Microsoft HPC Default Job Email Settings / Notifications

Tags: hpc, ansys

I've got a Microsoft HPC cluster setup and we're using an engineering application to submit jobs to the compute cluster queue. Users remote desktop to the head-node of the cluster to submit jobs to avoid file-transfer delays across our WAN, this leads to completed or failed jobs sitting for review for a long time.

Unfortunately we can't use the HPC Job Manager to submit jobs to the queue, we have to use the engineering application submission tool. That application doesn't have an option to send an email on the job status (completed, failed etc.)

In the HPC Job Manager > New Job there are options for "Send a notification when this job" starts / completes etc. which would be great if we could use that to submit.

All jobs submitted use the Default job template but on that template I don't options to edit or add email settings to it.

Is there an option I'm missing or is this even a possible configuration?